# How to pass commands in already running programs in C

Tags: c, command

So if you want to parse command line options when starting the program you use getopt(). But how are you doing this if the program is already running in the background? I couldn't find info. let's say for example that you have a server running, but you want to change something in the way it works. How to do it? I want to do this in Linux.

Answer (score 2):

There is no platform-independent way of doing this; the C programming language doesn't specify (or require the existance of) a mechanism to talk to a running program.

You're going to have to look for either platform-specific code, or some existing library which abstracts the platforms into something portable of its own.

In Linux, a [Unix domain socket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket) is one way of implementing this. Another is shared memory.

Comment: BTW, you could consider making your program a specialized HTTP server (e.g. using some HTTP server library like [libonion](http://www.coralbits.com/libonion/)...) ; then your user could open some special URL to communicate with your program.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Un*x you have [many options](http://tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node7.html).

A FIFO pipe looks reasonable and easy to implement :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways you can do this, but they all have a common theme - Interprocess communication.

My preferred way to do this is via some sort of sockets (typically these days I use ZMQ for these purposes, but if you're starting out, read up on sockets in general before you get caught up using ZMQ). Depending whether you're on Windows or some sort of Unix will dictate what sort of sockets you have available to you.

There are other ways to do this also - such as shared memory, but sockets would be your best bet especially since you mentioned "server". I suggest you study the "client server model".

Answer (score 0):

A simplest solution with server I have used - is to make file and ask server to read file once a 10 second. Put command there. That is cross platform).
Second more or less cross platform solution is to use some standard library for concurrency (pthread, for example), or to use new standard of C++ (thread and mutex libs). Make thread that will wait for some commands, while other will execute something.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a configuration file and have the program listen to changes to that file.

If you are programming in Linux you can use inotify (`#include <linux/inotify.h>`).

In MacOS/iOS use FSEvents.

In Windows use [FindFirstChangeNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365261%28VS.85%29.aspx).